# RStudio hangs on startup after Ubuntu 22.04 update

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I updated to Ubuntu 22.04 and now RStudio hangs when I try and start it.

I just get a blank screen and can't exit or quit except by killing the process.

**How can I get RStudio functioning correctly again?**

Answer (score 2):

This relates to an [existing issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9854).

The current solution is to reinstall RStudio - currently from the daily builds:
https://dailies.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is the only solution that worked for me

Open it from the terminal with the command: `usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio --no-sandbox`.
A fix is supposed to come out later this summer.

You can edit rstudio.desktop to make clicking the Rstudio icon work as well.

`sudo nano /usr/share/applications/rstudio.desktop`

Add `--no-sandbox` in the Exec-line

Comment: Yup that's a good alternative if you don't want to install the daily build. Did you try installing from the daily?

Comment: No, actually I didn't